# Element UI NavMenu gets out of sync with current route

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, element-ui

I'm using the Element UI `NavMenu` with `:router="true"`. It is working fine when I click on menu links (route changes and active menu item changes). The issue I'm having is that when I click on the browser navigation buttons (`back` and `forward`), the route and component change, but the `NavMenu` active tab does not change.

Is there an easy way to make sure the `NavMenu` and current route stay in sync with each other when using the browser navigation buttons? I'm using `vue-router` with `mode: 'history'`. I would have thought that this would be handled automatically.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I originally tried to implement [this answer](https://gist.github.com/languanghao/5f74ca361f22192ba774941a69fd275b) with no luck. I now have a working solution for this issue. In my navigation component, I have an `el-menu` with `:router="true" and`:default-active="activeLink"`.

Since I have a fairly simple Vue application, I did not want to loop over my router paths and build the NavMenu dynamically. This is a good practice, but I wanted to understand how it works at a basic level first.

From the `element-ui` docs, `default-active` controls the `index of currently active menu`. I added `activeLink` as a data property:

```
  data() {
    return {
      logo: logo,
      activeLink: null,
    }
  },
```

and then added a `watch` property as described in the gist linked above:

```
  watch: {
    $route (to, from) {
      this.activeLink = to.path;
    }
  },
```

The part I was missing was that the `index` and the `route` properties of the `el-menu-item` need to be the same. Also, we can add a `mounted` method to make sure that the correct nav link is made active no matter what path we load the app from:

```
  mounted: function(){
    this.activeLink = this.$route.path;
  },
```

That fixed the issue of the NavMenu getting out of sync when I use browser navigation buttons.

Comment: do you add these methods in the component file that has the el-menu element?

Comment: The Element UI doc should mention that it takes a bit of finessing to make it work in router mode!

Answer (score 3):

This was a pain to get to work. I couldn't get `beforeRouteUpdate()` to work at all, and `:default-active="$route.path"` *almost* works, but not if you have parameters for your routes. My current solution is to name all of my routes, and add menu items where the index is the name. Then the `default-active` value can just be taken from `$route.name`.

```
        <el-menu :default-active="$route.name" @select="menuSelect">
          <el-menu-item index="summary">
            <span slot="title">Summary</span>
          </el-menu-item>
          <el-menu-item index="memory">
            <span slot="title">Memory Overview</span>
          </el-menu-item>
          ...
        </el-menu>
```

And in your component:

```
  public menuSelect(index: string) {
    this.$router.push({
      name: index,
    });
  }
```

You can also avoid the annoying error `Navigating to current location ("summary") is not allowed` like this:

```
  public menuSelect(index: string) {
    if (this.$route.name !== index) {
      this.$router.push({
        name: index,
      });
    }
  }
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thanks @Timmmm for saving my day ;)